# eventsMatchingPredicate not finding last date in event spanning multiple days

Tags: ios, nspredicate, eventkit

I have an event (called "Test Event") which starts at 2 a.m. on November 6 and ends on 10 a.m. on November 24.  When I try to find the event by specifying a range of one day, I can find it for all days (November 6, November 7, ..., November 23) **except November 24**.

The following method is called every time the user chooses a new day:

```
- (void)loadItemsFromDate:(NSDate *)fromDate toDate:(NSDate *)toDate
{
    NSLog(@"loadItemsFromDate");

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@ to %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:fromDate], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:toDate]);

    // Create the predicate from the event store's instance method
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:fromDate
                                                             endDate:toDate
                                                           calendars:nil];

    NSLog(@"predicateFormat: %@", [predicate predicateFormat]);

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    self.currentDayEvents = [self.store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"single day events:");
    for(EKEvent *event in self.currentDayEvents)
    {
        NSLog(@"title: %@, start: %@, end: %@", event.title, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.startDate], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.endDate]);
    }
    NSLog(@"\n");
}
```

Here is the log when the user chooses November 6 (can find "Test Event"):

```
loadItemsFromDate
11/6/12, 12:00 AM to 11/6/12, 11:59 PM
predicateFormat: EKEventPredicate start:11/6/12, 12:00 AM; end:11/6/12, 11:59 PM; cals:(null)
single day events:
title: Vote, start: 11/6/12, 12:00 AM, end: 11/6/12, 11:59 PM
title: Test Event, start: 11/6/12, 2:00 AM, end: 11/24/12, 10:00 AM
```

November 7 through 22 all look similar to this log, which is for November 23 (can find "Test Event"):

```
loadItemsFromDate
11/23/12, 12:00 AM to 11/23/12, 11:59 PM
predicateFormat: EKEventPredicate start:11/23/12, 12:00 AM; end:11/23/12, 11:59 PM; cals:(null)
single day events:
title: Test Event, start: 11/6/12, 2:00 AM, end: 11/24/12, 10:00 AM
```

And here's the log for November 24 (does not work as expected since it doesn't return "Test Event"):

```
loadItemsFromDate
11/24/12, 12:00 AM to 11/24/12, 11:59 PM
predicateFormat: EKEventPredicate start:11/24/12, 12:00 AM; end:11/24/12, 11:59 PM; cals:(null)
single day events:
```

Why isn't it finding the event for November 24 even though the event ends at 10 a.m. that day?  I'm running iOS 6.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a bug in iOS code unfortunately. My steps to reproduce:

1. Create your test event exactly as you described above in the basic
   iOS calendar app.
2. Look at it in Month view and you will notice that
   there IS NO dot/marker on 11/24/2012... which to me indicates something fishy is going on. Then click on the 24th tile and note that the event IS actually listed.
3. Then change your event to an
   all-day event (effectively removing 2am from your start time and
   10am from your end time).
4. Look at it in Month view and you will notice that now there IS a dot/marker on 11/24/2012.

I'm not sure how to hack around this yet but I can verify that the code in my app is exhibiting the same problem as yours.

Comment: Interesting... I'll submit a bug to Apple.

Comment: Do you know if they confirmed the bug/fixed it yet?

Comment: They haven't confirmed it.

Comment: Looks like this is still a bug as of today. My quick fix: adjust the fromDate so it grabs from the very end of the previous day, then purge anything that doesn't actually cross the date span from the returned list of events.